# Play Framework Scala Functional Programming Confusion - Mappings and Compression

Tags: scala, playframework, functional-programming, playframework-2.0

I'm coming from Java (basic Scala for/field, map/filter understanding) and I'm having some trouble understanding a snippet of code from Scala Play-2.0 web framework...

```
private val productForm: Form[Product] = Form(
    mapping( /* The form's fields and their constraints */
    "ean" -> longNumber.verifying(
    "validation.ean.duplicate", Product.findByEan(_).isEmpty),
    "name" -> nonEmptyText,
    "description" -> nonEmptyText
    )(Product.apply)(Product.unapply) /* Functions to map between form and model */
)
```

I know what this does...

```
val strings1 = List("a", "b", "c", "d")
val strings2 = List("e", "f", "g", "h")
val stringsOfString = List(strings1, strings2)

val notA = for{
  stringList <- stringsOfString
  myString <- stringList
  if (myString charAt 0) != 'a'
} yield myString charAt 0

println(notA) // prints b, c, d, e, f, g, h
```

Like I understand that I can extract each thing from a list of things using "<-" and then filter using "if" and then yield a new list of things using "yield", but I don't understand what the above (Play 2.0) example translates to, in terms of map/reduce/filter and what not.

I mean I know what this does...

```
List(1,2,3,4,5) map (2*_) // the "_" represents each element in the list.
```

But I am confused by "Product.findByEan( _ )". What does the "_" refer to in this case - Product is not a List like in the above example.

I don't understand how you could map a string like "ean" from a list. I don't understand what is going on. Please explain this function mapping thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion here. The `->` and `<-` operators are two things completely independent from each other. As you correctly note, `<-` is used in `for` expressions, but `->` is just a left associative operator to create Tuple2 instances, so

```
1 -> 2 == (1, 2)
1 -> 2 -> 3 == ((1, 2), 3)
```

So basically you are passing tuples as the arguments for the `mapping` function.

As for the `_` notation in `Product.findByEan(_).isEmpty`, it's just a shorthand to write a function equivalent to this:

```
{ ean => Product.findByEan(ean).isEmpty }
```

Comment: That is so incredibly confusing. I mean I would expect that a -> b is the same thing as b <- a.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I don't know play, but it seems, that question is related to scala.
I tried to simplify your sample, according to your question(what is _):

```
object Main {
  "ean" -> longNumber.verifying("validation.ean.duplicate", Product.findByEan(_).isEmpty)
}

object longNumber {
  def verifying(s: String, f: String => Boolean): String = ???
}

object Product{
  def findByEan(s: String): Seq[Int] = ???
}
```

Look at Main

```
"ean" -> longNumber.verifying("validation.ean.duplicate", Product.findByEan(_).isEmpty)
```

this can be rewritten to

```
"ean" -> longNumber.verifying("validation.ean.duplicate", t => Product.findByEan(t).isEmpty)
```

longNumber.verifying takes some string and a function f: String => Boolean, does something with it and return String.
In product we just have simple function, that takes string and return Seq.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that in this code, `Product` is Slick mapping for some database table. Perhaps a `findByEan` is defined for `Product` object, therefore, I would assume `Product.findByEan(_)` is defined something like this:

```
def findByEan(ean: String): Option[Product] {
  // retrieve product
  // if product found return Some(product)
  // else return None
}
```

So `Product.findByEan(_)` is same as calling `Product.findByEan(ean => ean)`.